# How to print out text from a string

Tags: java, printing

I have now managed to create an upload in JSF that allows the user to upload a text file and I can also display it. I managed to print it to a printer that is connected to the client side. How can I print this text to a printer that is connected to the server side using Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, Once you upload the file you will have the entire file content, create a utility `PrintDocument` class and call it whenever you need printing.

```
public class PrintDocument {

  public void printText(String text) throws PrintException, IOException {

    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF8"));
    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    is.close();
  }
}

class PrintJobWatcher {
  boolean done = false;

  PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
      public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      void allDone() {
        synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
          done = true;
          System.out.println("Printing document is done ...");
          PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
      while (!done) {
        wait();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to get all printers, use `PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();`

Comment: Thank you very much i shall try this now, is there any way of sending it to print to a printer queue or the ip address of the printer rather than selecting the printer ?

Comment: that's your choice if you need to print default printer, just send it. if user choice, add a jsf popup for selecting printer